# Sublime Text 3 Search and Replace Project Using Regex

Tags: search, replace, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 18.04.  I need to do a Search and Replace across 100+ pages in a project directory.  I'd like to do this with a regex, if possible, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

I want to find `tabindex="nbr"` where `nbr` is an actual number.  I.e:  `tabindex="2"`.   I want to replace every instance with `tabindex="0"`.

I've tried this:

```
Find:  tabindex="\d"

Where:  /home/me/path/to/project/

Replace: tabindex="0"
```

But this does not work.  I get a `0 matches found` pop up.  I've tried other regex's with the same `0 matches found` message.

This has to be easier than I am making it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Did you enable Regular Expressions before finding?

Comment: Hmmm!   Did not know I had to do that.